# Nifi is not releasing RAM even after stopping

Tags: apache-nifi

Nifi is consuming more memory in RAM and it is not releasing after stopping also.
Below is the screenshot in which nifi has been shut down but it is not able to stop. The total RAM is 23GB and it is utilizing full and when I entered JPS command it is helding all the memory. Even if I kill the processid by JPS command it is not killing.

Is there any way garbage collection will efficiently. Any configuration required for the above problem. I have given 6 to 8 gb heap size in **bootstrap.conf**.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are two processes that NiFi runs -- one is the `bootstrap` and the other is the main application. If the main application dies, the bootstrap will restart it. Determine the `pid` of the bootstrap process by running `ps -ef | grep RunNiFi`. You should get a result like:

```
  502 31023 31021   0  9:48PM ttys002    0:03.37 /Users/alopresto/.jenv/versions/1.8/bin/java -cp /Users/alopresto/Workspace/nifi/nifi-assembly/target/nifi-1.10.0-SNAPSHOT-bin/nifi-1.10.0-SNAPSHOT/conf:/Users/alopresto/Workspace/nifi/nifi-assembly/target/nifi-1.10.0-SNAPSHOT-bin/nifi-1.10.0-SNAPSHOT/lib/bootstrap/* -Xms12m -Xmx24m -Dorg.apache.nifi.bootstrap.config.log.dir=/Users/alopresto/Workspace/nifi/nifi-assembly/target/nifi-1.10.0-SNAPSHOT-bin/nifi-1.10.0-SNAPSHOT/logs -Dorg.apache.nifi.bootstrap.config.pid.dir=/Users/alopresto/Workspace/nifi/nifi-assembly/target/nifi-1.10.0-SNAPSHOT-bin/nifi-1.10.0-SNAPSHOT/run -Dorg.apache.nifi.bootstrap.config.file=/Users/alopresto/Workspace/nifi/nifi-assembly/target/nifi-1.10.0-SNAPSHOT-bin/nifi-1.10.0-SNAPSHOT/conf/bootstrap.conf org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.RunNiFi start
```

You can then kill this process using `kill -9 31023` (the PID is the second column). This will kill the bootstrap. You can now kill the NiFi application process by running `kill -9 <nifi-pid>` (in my case `31024` as seen below from the output of `ps -ef | grep nifi.NiFi` and verified as `31023` being the parent (third column)).

```
  502 31024 31023   0  9:48PM ttys002    6:50.13 /Users/alopresto/.jenv/versions/1.8/bin/java -classpath /Users/alopresto/Workspace/nifi/nifi-assembly/target/nifi-1.10.0-SNAPSHOT-bin/nifi-1.10.0-SNAPSHOT/./conf:/Users/alopresto/Workspace/nifi/nifi-assembly/target/nifi-1.10.0-SNAPSHOT-bin/nifi-1.10.0-SNAPSHOT/./lib/jetty-schemas-3.1.jar:/Users/alopresto/Workspace/nifi/nifi-assembly/target/nifi-1.10.0-SNAPSHOT-bin/nifi-1.10.0-SNAPSHOT/./lib/nifi-runtime-1.10.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:/Users/alopresto/Workspace/nifi/nifi-assembly/target/nifi-1.10.0-SNAPSHOT-bin/nifi-1.10.0-SNAPSHOT/./lib/slf4j-api-1.7.26.jar:/Users/alopresto/Workspace/nifi/nifi-assembly/target/nifi-1.10.0-SNAPSHOT-bin/nifi-1.10.0-SNAPSHOT/./lib/nifi-api-1.10.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:/Users/alopresto/Workspace/nifi/nifi-assembly/target/nifi-1.10.0-SNAPSHOT-bin/nifi-1.10.0-SNAPSHOT/./lib/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.26.jar:/Users/alopresto/Workspace/nifi/nifi-assembly/target/nifi-1.10.0-SNAPSHOT-bin/nifi-1.10.0-SNAPSHOT/./lib/nifi-framework-api-1.10.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:/Users/alopresto/Workspace/nifi/nifi-assembly/target/nifi-1.10.0-SNAPSHOT-bin/nifi-1.10.0-SNAPSHOT/./lib/javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:/Users/alopresto/Workspace/nifi/nifi-assembly/target/nifi-1.10.0-SNAPSHOT-bin/nifi-1.10.0-SNAPSHOT/./lib/nifi-nar-utils-1.10.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:/Users/alopresto/Workspace/nifi/nifi-assembly/target/nifi-1.10.0-SNAPSHOT-bin/nifi-1.10.0-SNAPSHOT/./lib/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar:/Users/alopresto/Workspace/nifi/nifi-assembly/target/nifi-1.10.0-SNAPSHOT-bin/nifi-1.10.0-SNAPSHOT/./lib/nifi-properties-1.10.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:/Users/alopresto/Workspace/nifi/nifi-assembly/target/nifi-1.10.0-SNAPSHOT-bin/nifi-1.10.0-SNAPSHOT/./lib/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.26.jar:/Users/alopresto/Workspace/nifi/nifi-assembly/target/nifi-1.10.0-SNAPSHOT-bin/nifi-1.10.0-SNAPSHOT/./lib/logback-core-1.2.3.jar:/Users/alopresto/Workspace/nifi/nifi-assembly/target/nifi-1.10.0-SNAPSHOT-bin/nifi-1.10.0-SNAPSHOT/./lib/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.26.jar -Dorg.apache.jasper.compiler.disablejsr199=true -Xmx512m -Xms512m -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8000 -Djavax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly=true -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/urandom -Dsun.net.http.allowRestrictedHeaders=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.awt.headless=true -XX:+UseG1GC -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=sun.net.www.protocol -Dnifi.properties.file.path=/Users/alopresto/Workspace/nifi/nifi-assembly/target/nifi-1.10.0-SNAPSHOT-bin/nifi-1.10.0-SNAPSHOT/./conf/nifi.properties -Dnifi.bootstrap.listen.port=64753 -Dapp=NiFi -Dorg.apache.nifi.bootstrap.config.log.dir=/Users/alopresto/Workspace/nifi/nifi-assembly/target/nifi-1.10.0-SNAPSHOT-bin/nifi-1.10.0-SNAPSHOT/logs org.apache.nifi.NiFi
```

You can also take thread dumps using `$ nifi.sh dump <file-to-dump.txt>` which will put the thread dump into the named file. This captured output can help determine what went wrong.

Comment: RunNiFi process got killed but ps -ef | grep nifi.NiFi process id which I got it got killed but it is showing again in JPS.